# Error in installing venv for python3 on mac

Tags: python, pip

While installing a virtual environment by running the following command on terminal:

> python3 -m pip install --user venv

I'm encountering the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement venv
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for venv

Please help me with this! I believe since default python is version 2.x in macOS I must try installing virtualenv but I require venv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot install `venv` with `pip`: `venv` is a [module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) since Python 3.3. So you don't need to install it, just start using:

```
python3 -m venv path/to/new-venv
```

Answer (score 1):

Venv doesn't exists. I guess that you might want the package **virtualenv**.

Venv is commonly used as the name of virtual environment created by virtualenv.

So, the command is:

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv venv
```